# Getting only slug in otherwise null object on routed template

Tags: routing, slug

I'm trying to create a template route that allows me to get all of the attorneys that I've related to a specified practice area. I can get the slug easily, as my route looks like this:

`'attorneys/legal-services/(?P<slug>[^/]+)' => 'attorneys/legal-services'`

And sure enough, when I go to `/attorneys/legal-services/construction-law`, I can access the `{{ slug }}` variable and grab `construction-law`.

The problem I'm having is that everything else in the object I request with `craft.entries.slug(slug)` ends up being `NULL`.

A simple code sample like this:

```
{% extends '_layouts/two-column' %}
{% set practice = craft.entries.slug(slug) %}

{% block main %}
  <main class="page-body">
    <h1>Attorneys</h1>
    <h2>in {{ practice.title }}</h2>
    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('people').relatedTo(practice) %}
      <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </main>
{% endblock %}
```

will output all the content I request in my `for` loop, but `practice.title` is left empty.

When I `dump` the contents of the `practice` object out, I see this:

```
object(Craft\ElementCriteriaModel)[749]
  protected 'strictAttributes' => boolean false
  private '_elementType' => 
    object(Craft\EntryElementType)[742]
      protected 'componentType' => string 'ElementType' (length=11)
      private '_sourcesByContext' (Craft\BaseElementType) => null
      private '_classHandle' (Craft\BaseComponentType) => null
      public 'behaviors' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private '_initialized' (CApplicationComponent) => boolean true
      private '_e' (CComponent) => null
      private '_m' (CComponent) => null
  private '_supportedFieldHandles' => null
  private '_matchedElements' => null
  private '_matchedElementsAtOffsets' => null
  private '_cachedIds' => null
  private '_cachedTotal' => null
  protected 'classSuffix' => string 'Model' (length=5)
  private '_classHandle' (Craft\BaseModel) => null
  private '_attributeConfigs' (Craft\BaseModel) => 
    array (size=45)
      'ancestorDist' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'ancestorOf' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'archived' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 1
          'default' => boolean false
          'required' => boolean true
          'column' => string 'tinyint' (length=7)
          'unsigned' => boolean true
          'type' => string 'bool' (length=4)
          'min' => int 0
          'max' => int 255
      'dateCreated' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'dateUpdated' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'descendantDist' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'descendantOf' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'fixedOrder' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 1
          'default' => boolean false
          'required' => boolean true
          'column' => string 'tinyint' (length=7)
          'unsigned' => boolean true
          'type' => string 'bool' (length=4)
          'min' => int 0
          'max' => int 255
      'id' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'indexBy' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'level' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'limit' => 
        array (size=9)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'default' => int 100
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'locale' => 
        array (size=2)
          'column' => string 'locale' (length=6)
          'type' => string 'locale' (length=6)
      'localeEnabled' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 1
          'default' => boolean true
          'required' => boolean true
          'column' => string 'tinyint' (length=7)
          'unsigned' => boolean true
          'type' => string 'bool' (length=4)
          'min' => int 0
          'max' => int 255
      'nextSiblingOf' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'offset' => 
        array (size=9)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'default' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'order' => 
        array (size=2)
          'default' => string 'lft, postDate desc' (length=18)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'positionedAfter' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'positionedBefore' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'prevSiblingOf' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'relatedTo' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'ref' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'search' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'siblingOf' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'slug' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'status' => 
        array (size=2)
          'default' => string 'live' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'title' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'uri' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'with' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'childField' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'childOf' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'depth' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'parentField' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'parentOf' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'after' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'authorGroup' => 
        array (size=1)
          'type' => string 'string' (length=6)
      'authorGroupId' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'authorId' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'before' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'editable' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 1
          'default' => boolean false
          'required' => boolean true
          'column' => string 'tinyint' (length=7)
          'unsigned' => boolean true
          'type' => string 'bool' (length=4)
          'min' => int 0
          'max' => int 255
      'expiryDate' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'postDate' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'section' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
      'sectionId' => 
        array (size=8)
          'maxLength' => int 11
          'min' => int -2147483648
          'max' => int 2147483647
          'decimals' => int 0
          'type' => string 'number' (length=6)
          'unsigned' => boolean false
          'length' => int 10
          'column' => string 'integer' (length=7)
      'type' => 
        array (size=3)
          'model' => null
          'column' => string 'text' (length=4)
          'type' => string 'mixed' (length=5)
  private '_attributes' (Craft\BaseModel) => 
    array (size=9)
      'archived' => boolean false
      'fixedOrder' => boolean false
      'limit' => int 100
      'localeEnabled' => boolean true
      'offset' => int 0
      'order' => string 'lft, postDate desc' (length=18)
      'status' => string 'live' (length=4)
      'editable' => boolean false
      'slug' => string 'construction-law' (length=16)
  private '_extraAttributeNames' (Craft\BaseModel) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_errors' (CModel) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_validators' (CModel) => null
  private '_scenario' (CModel) => string '' (length=0)
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

As a result, I'm getting

```
<h1>Attorneys</h1>
<h2>in </h2>
```

even though I'm expecting to see the title of the practice area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `{% set practice = craft.entries.slug(slug).first() %}` to fetch the real `EntryModel`, and not just an `ElementCriteriaModel`.

I think the `relatedTo` criteria still works without it because that calls `.find()` implicitly when passed an `ElementCriteriaModel`, but that doesn't actually change what the `practice` variable references in the rest of the template.